# How to set swap memory in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Could anyone let me know how and where to set the swap memory in wso2 esb 5.0.0.
I am getting below warning when I restart esb server.

TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-07 15:30:33,682]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Swap Memory size (MB): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Installation+Prerequisites) document about the memory requirements of ESB 5.0.0. The swap memory and other JVM properties can be set at the config-validation.xml in /repository/conf/etc.

Comment: Thanks for the information, config-validation.xml in /repository/conf/etc is the location which has the default values for wso2esb which will be used to compare against the actual value set in the server. Setting the values here will not change the Swap memory value. Please correct me if I am wrong.